# Spark jobs not showing up in Hadoop UI in Google Cloud

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I created a cluster in Google Cloud and submitted a spark job. Then I connected to the UI following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces): I created an ssh tunnel and used it to open the Hadoop web interface. But the job is not showing up.

Some extra information:

1. If I connect to the master node of the cluster via ssh and run `spark-shell`, this "job" does show up in the hadoop web interface.
2. I'm pretty sure I did this before and I could see my jobs (both running and already finished). I don't know what happened in between for them to stop appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was running my jobs in local mode. My code had a `.master("local[*]")` that was causing this. After removing it, the jobs showed up in the Hadoop UI as before.